# In Rails how to cleanly only execute code if variable is set to true?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In my layouts/books I have my navigation code that is hitting all my views for books then yields.

I also have my header code that is hitting all my views for books then yields. Really I only want my header code to hit the index and show but not my order.

I've tried putting something like below around my header to:

```
<% if @render.header == true %>
 <div class="header">
  HTML
 </div>
<% end %>
```

Then putting in my views:

```
<% if @render.header == true/false %>
```

I end up getting undefined method `header'. I've also tried things like:

What do I need to adapt this into to get this to work? Should I be putting something into my controller?

EDIT: I've also attempted the following in both my layout/books and in index:

```
<% @render.header = true %>
```

This leads to undefined meathod "header= "

I can get this to work using a global variable but that has got to be a bad idea.

Comment: What does '@render' stands for?

Comment: `<% @render.header == true/false %>`: Are you trying to set the header variable for @render? Then you must use a single equals sign =: `<% @render.header = true # or false %>` A double equals sign == is used for evaluating equality of two statements as you correctly doing in the context of the if statement.

Comment: I'm trying to set a variable around the header to run only if the view is marked for true. I've tried putting <% @render.header = true %> within the layout/books and then in the index. I end up getting undefined method `header='

Comment: Try using a simple variable like `@render_header` or `@header` instead of `@render.header`

Comment: @Finn I actually updated the code. I was able to use a global variable and it worked. I think I need something to use in the controller as using a global variable makes me feel icky.

Comment: Awesome! What do you perceive the difference to be between setting `@render_header` and your previous goal of setting `@render.header`? For all that matters, it is an equally 'global' variable. Alternatively, it sounds like you have looked into the layout option. You may know, you can set a specific layout to be rendered for all (or only some) actions of a controller. Here is an in-depth explanation: http://railscasts.com/episodes/7-all-about-layouts?view=asciicast

Comment: Lastly, what I also sometimes make use of are the two variables `controller_name` and `action_name` that are accessible in views and are automatically set by Rails. You could do something like `<% if controller_name == 'books' && (action_name == 'show' || action_name == 'edit') %>` as the conditional for rendering your header.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after flailing around I went from in my layout/book:

```
<% if @render.header == true/false %>
```

To:

```
<% $header == true/false %>
```

Which worked but it's global. And finally to updating my controller for both index and show to:

```
def index
@header = true
end
```

And then my layout/book to:

```
<% @header == true %>
```

So yeah. Variable types.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
if @render && @render.header
```

Answer (score 0):

This is nothing terribly different from what I already pointed out in the comments but here it goes:

First of all, `@render` just defaults to `nil` in views. So when you are trying to set the value for header, it fails with `undefined method 'header=' for nil:NilClass` (because Rails looks for a method called `#header=` for the nil:NilClass).

#### Use a plain variable @render_header

You can instead just set a plain variable, such as `@render_header`, in your controller or view (before rendering header):

```
<% @render_header = true %>
```

and then in your header

```
<% if @render_header %>
# ...
```

#### Use a hash for @render = { header: true }

Or, if you really want to use the `@render` variable, you can just set it to be a hash:

```
<% @render = { header: true } %>
```

and then in your header

```
<% if @render.present? && @render[:header] %>
# ...
```

This is almost like what you originally wrote.

#### Set the variable automatically based on controller action

If you need this variable to be set for multiple controller actions, you can look into [controller filters](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#filters). They work just like callbacks but for controllers.

For example, you could do:

```
class MyController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_render_header_to_true, only: [:new, :show]

  # ...

  private

  def set_render_header_to_true
    @render_header = true
  end
end
```

That way, the variable would automatically be set to true for the :new and the :show action. If you had multiple controllers needing to set render_header to true, you could move the `set_render_header_to_true` method to the ApplicationController. For example, this would work:

```
class ApplicationController

  private

  def set_render_header_to_true
    @render_header = true
  end
end

class MyController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_render_header_to_true, only: [:new, :show]
  # ...
end

class MyOtherController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_render_header_to_true, except: :index
  # ...
end
```

#### Set a custom layout from your controller

You can also specify a specific layout to be rendered based on the controller action:

```
class MyController < ApplicationController
  layout 'with_header'
  # Use the line below to render header only for specific actions,
  # such as new and edit
  # layout 'with_header', :only => [:show, :edit]

  # ...
end
```

You can even define a method to dynamically choose the layout:

```
class MyController < ApplicationController
  layout :determine_layout
  def determine_layout
    if action_name == :new
      'layout1'
    elsif action_name == :show
      'layout2'
    else
      'application'
    end
  end
  # ...
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think i understand your problem. Anyway you can also use content_for. For example, if add to layout/books.html.erb:

```
<%= yield :header %>
```

For index/show/etc views with header:

```
<% content_for :header do %>
  <div class="header">
    HTML
  </div>
<% end %>
```